# How to sort a list with sublists (common Lisp)

Tags: sorting, lisp, common-lisp

How to sort a list with sublists?

```
(setq list '((0) (1) (2) (0 1 5) (0 1 3) (0 1 5) (0 3 0) (0) (1) 
             (2 7 19) (0 0 3 0)))

; restricting the sort to only the first element:

(sort (copy-seq list) #'< :key #'car)

--> ((0) (0 1 5) (0 1 3) (0 1 5) (0 3 0) (0) (0 0 3 0) (1) (1) (2) (2 7 19))
```

The output I am looking for is sort on all elements of the sublist:

```
--> ((0) (0) (0 0 3 0) (0 1 3) (0 1 5) (0 1 5) (0 3 0) (1) (1) (2) (2 7 19))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Start by defining a function that determines whether one list is less than another.  The following example assumes that the lists can only contain numbers:

```
(defun list< (a b)
  (cond ((null a) (not (null b)))
        ((null b) nil)
        ((= (first a) (first b)) (list< (rest a) (rest b)))
        (t (< (first a) (first b))) ))
```

Armed with this function, you can now sort the list of lists.

```
(sort (copy-seq list) #'list<)
```

Comment: Thanks to you all. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Seems odd that Lisp doesn't have a built-in function that compares two lists itemwise. There are a few assumptions it would have to make, but it would seem to make sense to have a reasonable default that you could still always define your own function to override...

Answer (score 0):

**To sort on all elements of a sublist, use a custom function for the sort *predicate* or *key*.** Change the *sort predicate* to a custom function that can determine the order of two sublists. Alternatively, change the *sort key* to a custom function that reduces the sublist to a sortable value.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to understand the use of custom functions.